# Terminal probabilities of a probability matrix Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, probability, markov-chains

I have a matrix m that represents the probabilities transitioning from states to states.

E.g. for the sample below I will always get stuck in states 1,3,4, and state 2 I will randomly transition to one of the 4 states.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.eye(4)
m[1] = 0.25
print(m)
```

```
[[1.   0.   0.   0.  ]

 [0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]

 [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]

 [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]]
```

How do I find a matrix representing the eventual end state following infinite transitions?

E.g. if I do this, I get intuitive result of states 1,3,4 --> 100% sticking in 1,3,4 but state 2 --> 1/3 chance ending up in all the others. Since all cases from state 2 eventually allocated evenly between 1,3,4 through multiple transitions.

```
t = m
for _ in range(100_000):
    t = t @ t
print(t)
```

```
[[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]

 [0.33333333 0.         0.33333333 0.33333333]

 [0.         0.         1.         0.        ]

 [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]]
```

How can I calculate this without using repeated multiplications? I thought it corresponds to the eigenvector/eigenvalues of the matrix, but I get something very different when I calculate this.

```
np.linalg.eig(m)
```

```
[[0.        , 0.9486833 , 0.        , 0.        ],

[1.        , 0.31622777, 0.31622777, 0.31622777],

[0.        , 0.        , 0.9486833 , 0.        ],

[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.9486833 ]]
```

Is there a methodology to calculate this using numpy? I need it to work for an arbitrary matrix, but there will be a known list of terminal states and positive probability of reaching these from all other states.

At the moment I am thinking of using the repeated multiplication method but it feels suboptimal and something there should be a function/trick that can calculate without looping.

I was reading this but didn't fully understand what the methodology is and how to implement it.

https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m20x06/public_html/Lecture14.pdf

I also looked in this question. People seemed to give some tips for hand-solving but not a general algorithm:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003258/calculating-the-probability-of-reaching-each-absorbing-state-in-markov-chain

Comment: [linalg.matrix_power(m, 100_000)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html)?

Comment: Hi JohanC this is the method I could think of but wondering if there is a trick to calculate more easily.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "more easily"?

Comment: @amzon-ex Less of a brute force approach, that is more elegant, taking advantage of some property of matrix algebra.

Comment: Take your point @JohanC and also that this is more of a maths question. See my answer below for a solution it is fair that this might be more of  a maths question. I did try searching and moulding find something I could understand, and understand how to implement in numpy. See here quite often when it is a maths question they point out specific solving tricks rather than some more general-purpose algorithm. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457848/probability-of-absorption-in-markov-chain

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm interested in the specific probabilities, rather than which states are terminal. Experimentally I found this works better if I place all terminal states next to each other in the matrix so that there is a submatrix  which is the identity. Also .matrix_power and @ operations in practice very fast for the size of matrix I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend pointed out the following trick.

Eigendecomposition means we can write the original matrix as

V x D x V^-1

Where D is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues, and V is the eigenvector.

If we multiply this by itself infinite times, it is

V x D^inf x V^-1

Which we can calculate in numpy using the below.

```
d, v = np.linalg.eig(m)
v @ np.diag(d >= 1).astype(int) @ np.linalg.inv(v)
```

Since if the diagonal values are < 1 they will tend to 0 as we multiply (assuming we have a matrix with valid probabilities, and all states can reach the terminal states).

Comment: I think you'll want to look for the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue = 1 -- these eigenvectors are the so-called stationary distributions or steady-state vectors. Also, I think you'll need to be careful about the convention for the structure of the matrix -- it might be convenient to work with a transition matrix in which the columns sum to 1, rather than the rows summing to 1, as your example showed. So maybe look at the eigenvalues/vectors of the transpose of your example.

Comment: The eigenvalues/vectors decomposition is a lot of work computationally -- I think you should be able to find absorbing states, or, more generally, absorbing subsets, by just inspecting the transition matrix. Maybe there's a graph-theoretic way to look at the transition matrix.